# What is the difference "getByText" and "getByTestId" ? In testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, testing, styled-components, react-testing-library

What is the difference between `getByText` and `getByTestId`?

When I had tested a React component, there were some gaps between these two functions.

The test failed in `getByText` code, but it succeeded in `getByTestId`.

I have code that when an element was clicked, the color of the title changed to red.

Why this is the difference?

I omitted styled-components of `Container` and `Content`. This has props 'toggled' to change the color to red.

Here is the `getByText` code:

```js
const { getByText } = render(<ListPresenter content={ListText} />);
const colorChangedText = getByText(/the party/);
fireEvent.click(colorChangedText);
screen.debug(); // The result of render I want !
expect(colorChangedText).toHaveStyle("color: red");    * failed
```

Here is the `getByTestId` code:

```
const { getByText } = render(<ListPresenter content={ListText} />);
fireEvent.click(getAllByTestId("list-element-toggle")[0]);
screen.debug(); // The result of render I want !
const colorChangedText = getAllByTestId("list-element-content")[0];
expect(colorChangedText).toHaveStyle("color: red");   * success
```

Here is the rendered component:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container
        className="container"
        data-testid={"list-element-toggle"}
        toggled={state[data.id - 1]}
     >
        <Content className="content" data-testid={"list-element-content"} toggled={state[data.id - 1]}>
          {data.titleChild}.  // This text had been changed to red color when i was clicked.
        
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I would suggest usnig getByText wherever you can then it follows the ethos of the testing what the user sees, does, i.e. not testing implementation details. getByTestId only when there isn't anything you cant easily latch onto from your UI. getByTestId: The user cannot see (or hear) these, so this is only recommended for cases where you can't match by role or text or it doesn't make sense (e.g. the text is dynamic). https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[react-testing-library cheatsheet](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet)

- **ByText** find by element text content
- **ByTestId** find by data-testid attribute

I've found that selecting by text can be a bit finicky and usually end up adding a `testid` attribute to query/target the *exact* element I want.

My guess is the `getByText` may not be returning the correct element/wrapper.

From your test code

```
render(<ListPresenter content={ListText} />);
```

It's not clear to me what the text in the test may be. It's not even clear to me if `ListPresenter` is the `Component` in the last snippet. For example, what is `data.titleChild`?

See also [Which query should I use?](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query)

Queries Accessible to Everyone

> `getByText`: Not useful for forms, but this is the number 1 method a
> user finds most non-interactive elements (like divs and spans).

Test IDs

> `getByTestId`: The user cannot see (or hear) these, so this is only
> recommended for cases where you can't match by role or text or it
> doesn't make sense (e.g. the text is dynamic).

As a fallback there also [Manual Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query#manual-queries).